# Can not understand the sentence

Tags: meaning

“ A company spokeswoman told the Guardian: “We operate under the constraints of US laws, which vary by circumstance.” ”
I can not understand what varies. Constraints or laws?

Comment: Either or both. You’ll need more than grammar to disambiguate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the constraints of US laws vary.
"US laws" is an adjective of "the constraints".
So,What varies is "the constraints".

Thinking a twice,the constraints are varied by US laws.
The constraints are never varied by itself.

So it is a good question.

But "We operate under the constraints..."

"the constraints" have the most influence on "our operation".
And on the grammer,the subject is also "the constraints".
At last,the constraints may not be varied however the laws vary.

So my answer is "the constraints".